# Error using scanf() for user input

Tags: c

I am getting a weird problem while using `scanf()` to store data into a union.

Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

union Student
{
    float score;
    char grade;
};

int main(void)
{
    union Student jack;

    printf("Enter student score : ");
    scanf("%f", &jack.score);
    printf("Score : %f", jack.score);

    jack.score=0;

    printf("Enter student grade : ");
    scanf("%c", &jack.grade);
    printf("Grade : %c", jack.grade);

}
```

I get the following output

```
searock@searock-desktop:~/Desktop$ ./union
Enter student score : 12
Score : 12.000000Enter student grade : Grade :
```

but if I change my code to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

union Student
{
    float score;
    char grade;
};

int main(void)
{
    union Student jack;

    printf("Enter student grade : ");
    scanf("%c", &jack.grade);
    printf("Grade : %c\n", jack.grade);

    printf("Enter student score : ");
    scanf("%f", &jack.score);
    printf("Score : %f\n", jack.score);

}
```

It gives me the exact output [correct output]. I know this is not a good example, but can someone explain me what's going wrong?

**Modified Code :** Add \n before format string. [scanf("\n%c", &ch);]

```
#include <stdio.h>

    union Student
    {
        float score;
        char grade;
    };

    int main(void)
    {
        union Student jack;

        printf("Enter student score : ");
        scanf("%f", &jack.score);
        printf("Score : %f", jack.score);

        jack.score=0;

        printf("Enter student grade : ");
        scanf("\n%c", &jack.grade);
        printf("Grade : %c", jack.grade);

    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by exact output? can you explain a bit mor.

Comment: @mohammad shams exact output = correct output

Comment: What's wrong with my question? Why have I been voted down?

Comment: You should explain what the correct output should look like, and what exactly is confusing you about the "incorrect" output. It's not really that clear what exactly you mean by "going wrong".

Comment: @sth I am sorry if I have used the incorrect word[exact output], but I have included the wrong output and after all the program is not so huge that it takes time to guess a small output.

Comment: @sth Ok I admit, I am completely wrong. I should have specified the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, the first `scanf()` reads a number up to but not including the newline (assuming you don't type just blanks and newlines; if you do, it will continue waiting for input until you provide a number or a non-number - where blanks etc do not count as either a number or a non-number).  Then the second `scanf()` with the '`%c`' format specifier does not skip white space (unlike most other format specifiers) and reads the newline (assuming you typed a newline immediately after the end of the number; if you typed something else - white space or a letter, perhaps, it reads that character), completely ignoring anything you typed on the second line.  (Indeed, when I run the code, it does not wait for me to enter anything for the second lot of input.  Try typing "3.14+C" or "3.14C" and a newline.)

In the second example, the first `scanf()` reads the first character.  The second `scanf()` skips over white space, including newlines, until it finds either a number or something that is definitively not a number (like a letter).

This is a beautiful demonstration of why most people avoid `scanf()`; it is very difficult to provide satisfactory control over it.  You would be better off reading lines (perhaps using `fgets()`; definitely not using `gets()`) and then parsing them with `sscanf()`.  You would then get sane behaviour for both examples.

Note that your problem is completely unrelated to the use of a `union`; your code is fine in the way that is working.  Your problem is all tied up with the use of `scanf()`.

Minor recommendation: when printing lines of output - other than prompts - include a newline at the end of the format string.

Comment: Thanks for the beautiful explanation. Thanks a lot : )

Answer (score 2):

The difference is because of the `\n` in the string.  These prevent the string from being cached in the output buffer and instead are immediately displayed on the screen.

Comment: I have removed /n from program but it still gives me the same error. I request you to copy the code the code and try running it. I am clueless  about what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you read a float and then the following character, which will be the newline that follows the float (you pressed the Enter key after inputting the float).

IN the second example the `scanf()` format specifiers include that newline, so the first `scanf()` reads a character followed by a newline and the second `scanf()` reads a float followed by a newline.

Comment: I am sorry but I can't understand what you are trying to say.